# jQuery selectors - how to select elements on multiple criteria including the type of their "next" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery I need to select elements that are:
under the "menu" DIV only
AND are DT elements
AND are followed by a DD element

In this sample HTML I would only want to select ids "select_me1" and "select_me2"

```
<html><body>
    <div id="menu">
        <dl>
            <dt id="dont_select1"><a href="#">don't 1</a></dt>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt id="dont_select2"><a href="#">don't 2</a></dt>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt id="dont_select3"><a href="#">don't 3</a></dt>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt id="select_me1"><a>select me 1</a></dt>
            <dd id="community-sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt id="select_me2"><a>select me 2</a></dt>
            <dd id="state-sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div id="other">
        <dl>
            <dt id="else1"><a href="#">else 1</a></dt>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt id="else2-main"><a>else 2</a></dt>
            <dd id="else2-sub">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can go a bit backwards here, like this:

```
​$("#menu dd").prev("dt")
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MBHCz/).  This goes to `#menu` using an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), finds all [descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `<dd>` elements with an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) then uses [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to go back to the `<dt>` sibling that immediately precedes it, if there is one.

Comment: Why is would "this" within  $("#menu dd").prev("dt").each{} give me an array of length 1 rather than the dt element itself??

Comment: @Young - `this` should refer to the element, you can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/MBHCz/2/

Answer (score 0):

This will select `<dd>` elements that have a previous `<dt>` element. Then it uses `.prev()` to traverse back to its sibling `<dt>`.

```
$('#menu dt + dd').prev()
```